# Parsing string to an array of strings in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have a string in this format:

```
"dataA\r\r\n" + "dataB\r\r\n" + "dataC\r\r\n" + "dataD"
```

The last data doesn't have `"\r\r\n"`.

I would like to parse it and change to it an array of strings:

```
["dataA", "dataB", "dataC", "dataD"]
```

I am wondering what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Don't you want `dataC` two times?

Comment: Yea, it was my mistake. I have changed it.

Comment: You have four strings.

Comment: That is a really wonky format. CRLF is `\r\n` but I've never seen CRCRLF formatted files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "dataA\r\r\n" + "dataB\r\r\n" + "dataC\r\r\n" + "dataD"
  #=> "dataA\r\r\ndataB\r\r\ndataC\r\r\ndataD"

str.split
  #=> ["dataA", "dataB", "dataC", "dataD"]
```

See the 4th paragraph of the doc for [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split). Ruby's definition of "whitespace" is given in the doc for [String#strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-strip). For

```
str = "a" + "b\t\t" + "c\n\n\n" + "d\v\v" + "e\f" + "f\r\r" + "g  " + "h"

str.split
  #=> ["ab", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

is therefore equivalent to

```
 str.split(/[\t\n\v\f\r \0]+/)
   #=> ["ab", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

Search for "Backslash Notation" [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals) for definitions of these backslash characters: horizontal tab, line feed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space.

Answer (score 4):

You could split your concatenated string by passing `\r\r\n` which is a common point between each value:

```
a = "dataA\r\r\n" + "dataB\r\r\n" + "dataC\r\r\n" + "dataD"
p a.split(/\r\r\n/)
# => ["dataA", "dataB", "dataC", "dataD"]
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.